# How do I create a STL file from a 2 dimensional grid of data

Tags: 3d-models, stl

Given a large set of data, I was able to create a 3D graph in Microsoft Excel.  How can I create a STL file similar to this graph to create a physical model of this graph?
[image]

Comment: Are you wanting to print the negative object (clear space below) or the part above?"

Do you have a sample of data that you used to generate it?

Comment: I want a print that looks like the graph.  I have the data used in creating the graph.

Answer (score 1):

for that you can use openSCAD.
Data can be represented as a multi-array and we can iterate on it via for loop

```
// data structure is x,y,z where z is value 
arrayOfData=[[0,10,4],[0,21,9],[0,13,8],[0,41,2],[1,0,4],[2,0,180],[7,0,90]];    

for(a=[0:1:6])  translate([arrayOfData[a][0], arrayOfData[a][1],0])  cylinder(arrayOfData[a][2],2,.5,false);
```

And where you get the model it can be intersected with a cube to get the desired shape.

[image]

Comment: I think the trick is to ensure that your CAD tool creates a mesh connecting the desired data points (and not connecting where you don't want it to).  Can you eleaborate on this?

Comment: that all depends on the desired output. As per attached example, I can see a series of cones. Playing with the cylinder will allow to connect -disconnect points and finally generated object can be intersected with cube.

Comment: OpenSCAD has a surface function that does this, no need to re-implement!

Comment: As per OP I was thinking about graph - so no harm here @esoterik

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this using the openSCAD using the surface command.

From the [openSCAD documentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Other_Language_Features#Surface):

```
//surface.scad
surface(file = "surface.dat", center = true, convexity = 5);
%translate([0, 0,5])cube([10,10,10], center =true);
```

And creating a space separated data file:

```
#surface.dat
10 9 8 7 6 5 5 5 5 5 
9 8 7 6 6 4 3 2 1 0 
8 7 6 6 4 3 2 1 0 0
7 6 6 4 3 2 1 0 0 0
6 6 4 3 2 1 1 0 0 0
6 6 3 2 1 1 1 0 0 0
6 6 2 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
6 6 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Then a STL can be exported of the data in openSCAD.